# Stop automatically opening Photos.app when inserting formatted SD card

Tags: macos, photos.app, sd-card

Whenever I put in my SD card, the Photos app opens automatically. I can set it to not open on a per-device basis, but since I format my SD card frequently that doesn't really help.

How can I stop this? I don't really ever want to use the Photos app at all.

Answer (score 4):

Image Capture manages which app is launched for a device. You can disable this functionality entirely by running the following then logging out:

```
defaults write com.apple.ImageCapture disableHotPlug -bool TRUE
```

Comment: +1 but I so wish you could micro-manage these settings :/ [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) can still do it for older device types, but doesn't cover modern devices like SD Cards.